# understanding scipy.stats.chisquare

Tags: scipy, chi-squared

Can someone help me with scipy.stats.chisquare? I do not have a statistical / mathematical background, and I am learning scipy.stats.chisquare with this data set from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test

The Wikipedia article gives the table below as an example, stating the Chi-squared value based on it is approximately 24.6. I am to use scipy.stats to verify this value and calculate the associated p value.

[image]

I have found what looks like the most likely formula solutions to help me here

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html

[image]

As I am new to statistics, and also the use of scipy.stats.chisquare I am just not sure of the best approach, and how best to enter the data from provided table into the arrays, and whether to supply expected values? from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That data is a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table).  SciPy has the function [`scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html) that applies the chi-square test to a contingency table.  It is fundamentally just a reqular chi-square test, but when applied to a contingency table, the expected frequencies are calculated under the assumption of independence (`chi2_contingency` does this for you), and the degrees of freedom depends on the number of rows and columns (`chi2_contingency` calculates this for you, too).

Here's how you can apply the chi-square test to that table:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency


table = np.array([[90, 60, 104, 95],
                  [30, 50,  51, 20],
                  [30, 40,  45, 35]])

chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(table)

print(f"chi2 statistic:     {chi2:.5g}")
print(f"p-value:            {p:.5g}")
print(f"degrees of freedom: {dof}")
print("expected frequencies:")
print(expected)
```

Output:

```
chi2 statistic:     24.571
p-value:            0.00040984
degrees of freedom: 6
expected frequencies:
[[ 80.53846154  80.53846154 107.38461538  80.53846154]
 [ 34.84615385  34.84615385  46.46153846  34.84615385]
 [ 34.61538462  34.61538462  46.15384615  34.61538462]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Warren Weckesser that is extremely helpful. I am curious about the .g you used in the print formatting I am trying to search that by its name.

Comment: That's the "general format" for formatting floating point values.  Check out ["Format Specification Mini-Language"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language); scroll down to the table of codes that follows the sentence "The available presentation types for floating point and decimal values are:".

Comment: When to use below chi-squared?

1. from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

2. from scipy.stats import chisquare

3. from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
    from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

Comment: That's a really low `p-value` - and given the discrepancy between expected and actual frequencies it can not be representing the typical _significance testing_  `p-value` : so what does it mean here?

Comment: @WestCoastProjects, it is the p-value computed using the chi-square test.  What is the problem with the value?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  Rephrasing my comment: the actual frequencies are highly divergent from the expected ones: so how canwe have a super low p-value here? Typically a p-value of 0.01 reflects a high correspondence to the null hypothesis: here we have 25X _better_ (lower) p-value yet the expected/actuals are dissimilar.   I am reading up more on chi-square to understand what their p-values actually mean here.

Comment: You have it backwards.  A low p-value is evidence *against* the null hypothesis.  In this case, the null hypothesis is that there is no association among the categories.  A large discrepancy of the frequencies from the expected frequencies suggests that there *is* some sort of association or dependence.  Roughly: large discrepancy ⇒ large chi-square statistic ⇒ small p-value.